# How to create iterable `function *() {}` via `new Function()` interface in ES6

Tags: javascript, iterator

The title stand for itself, there's a new iterable function interface in ES6, and the question is fairly simple, how to create an iterable function that supports `yield` via `new Function(...)` interface,

P.S.

I've tried doing

```
var f = function *() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}
```

in Google Chrome console, and then doing f.toString() it gave the following output:

```
function* () {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}
```

not sure however how to deal with it... when I try the following:

```
var g = new Function(`
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
`);
```

It produces error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to use `new Function()`?

Comment: I have a piece of dynamic code that is generated on the fly, it would be great if I could use it in conjunction with new ES6 features...

Comment: I think you have to put everything in one line

Comment: He uses the tick quotes which allow you to do the exact opposite, break code into multiple lines, unlike single or double quotes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to be interested in this:

```
var GeneratorFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(function*(){}).constructor
var g = new GeneratorFunction("a", "yield a * 2");
var iterator = g(10);
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 20
```

This is an example from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/GeneratorFunction

It makes basically what you want, looks like you were just looking at the wrong constructor.